# Node.js and mongodb: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am following this Node.js and mongodb tutorial with javascript (https://www.raywenderlich.com/2663-how-to-write-a-simple-node-js-mongodb-web-service-for-an-ios-app).

I am getting an error when I run node and mongodb from terminal then go to http://localhost:3000/items. The error appears to be in this block of code:

```
app.get('/:collection', function(req, res) { //A
   var params = req.params; //B
   collectionDriver.findAll(req.params.collection, function(error, objs) { //C
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); } //D
          else {
              if (req.accepts('html')) { //E
                  res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection}); //F
              } else {
              res.set('Content-Type','application/json'); //G
                  res.send(200, objs); //H
              }
         }
    });
});
```

In the code above this, I set the collectiondriver database:

```
var collectionDriver;
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort)); //B
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { //C
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1); //D
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("MyDatabase");  //E
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db); //F
});
```

The error when I go to localhost:3000/items is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
    at /Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/index.js:32:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/Users/username/Documents/NodeTutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Line 32 in index.js starts with "collectionDriver.findAll". What is the reason findAll() is undefined?

The expected output of the page in localhost:3000/items should look like the following as explained in the tutorial:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong? I am using mongodb version 1.3.23 (like the tutorial uses)

Comment: did you add the code to open the database connection? The error indicates `collectionDriver` is not set. In the article you linked, there's some setup code to initialize this value. That could should go above the code you pasted here.

Comment: @AustinGreco I posted the code where I set it.

Answer (score 1):

Node js runs asynchronously. In your case, I think the "`collectionDriver`" is not getting initialized before you use it. Try to use [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) to make them synchronized. Make sure your "`collectionDriver`" is initialized before you call .findAll(...).

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: So the collectionDriver is not getting initialized when I say 'collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db)', as in the code?

Comment: No, it is getting initialized but it is not getting initialized before the .findAll(..) method is called.  The main reason for this behavior is the asynchronous nature of Node js.  For simple testing, initialize the "collection drive" within the app.get(..) function itself. Ideally, it should work. if it works, then you can confirm the source of the issue.

Comment: Ok, I did what you suggested (initialize collectionDriver inside get()), but then localhost:3000/items only shows a pair of brackets {} and not what the output should look like in the original post.

Comment: If you are getting {} as a response, then it's clear that you are able to connect to the database. Check whether the database name and the collection name is proper in the code. If they are fine, you should be able to get the contents as a response back.  Your initial error seems to have gone now. I guess its because of the asynchronous nature then.

Comment: Also check if the collection name in mongo db actually contains any records or not ?

Comment: The db does not contain anything yet, as per the tutorial

Comment: You gotta add something in the DB to get some content as a response.  Probably the tutorial could have assumed that you will fill that eventually.  I guess that solves your problem. Thank you .